# Wordpress custom post type pagination with main "projects" page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

So I have a page called "Projects" and It's supposed to show the first project. I have other projects created but the pagination doesn't work, becaouse it redirects to an URL that's empty. Actually, if I go to the project on the backend and follow the permalink, it doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. Can you provide more information/context/code examples?

Comment: If I had to blindly guess, I'd say that there might be a page or post with the same slug as 'projects', and it's causing the issue you're seeing. This has happened to me before. But beyond that, we'd need some more information.